# Where is the location of /SiteAssets for sharepoint foundation server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I want to change the company logo.so under the site settings, looks and feel, Title, Description, and logo, when I upload the .jpg, it only loads the logo to the homepage, but doesn't populate down through the rest of the subsites.
any suggestions.?

do I need to upload the image to the /site assets folder?

if so, where on the server is that /site asset located?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually change to all the subsites, it does not automatically drill down.

Another option is to use the PowerShell and apply the logo to all sites. You can use following PwoerShell

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$siteurl = "https://test.sp2010.dev"
$sitelogo = "/Style Library/My Project/Images/logo.png"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
 $web.SiteLogoUrl = $sitelogo
 $web.Update()
 $web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. i tried it, but am having a few issues. i open PS as admin, then i run "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" - thats fine. then my script

Comment: $siteurl = "http://server01/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx"
$sitelogo = "/Style Library/image.jpg"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
 $web.SiteLogoUrl = $sitelogo
 $web.Update()
 $web.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()

Comment: Results in the following error. The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the collection: "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".
At C:\Users\administrator.ME\Desktop\Update_Logo.ps1:4 char:17
+ foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator

Comment: so above, is my PS1 script and the error message, hopefully someone can advise on whats going wrong?